# Chords $AB$ and $AC$ divide the area of the circle into three equal parts.If the angle $BAC$ is the root of the equation,$f(x)=0$,then find $f(x)$

Tags: geometry

$A$ is a point on the circumference of a circle.Chords $AB$ and $AC$ divide the area of the circle into three equal parts.If the angle $BAC$ is the root of the equation,$f(x)=0$,then find $f(x).$

I tried to solve it,but after some time,i got stuck.Let $O$ is the center and $r$ is the radius of the circle.Then as angle$BAC=\theta$,so angle $BOC=2\theta$,area of $BACA=\frac{\pi r^2}{2}$.Thereafter i stuck.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area  is found as:

$$ =\int ^{\theta/2} _ {-\theta/2} \rho^2 d t $$

where

$$ \rho = 2 r \cos t $$

The area relation is found by integration. To solve for $\theta,$ a transcendental equation a numerical method is suitable.

Area enclosed by chords = $ r^2 ( t + \sin t) = \pi r^2 /3 $

$$ \theta + \sin \theta = \frac{\pi}{3} $$

Answer (score 2):

If the circle is divided in such a way, then it is reasonable to assume the $2$ outer-parts are symmetrically about diameter $AB$.

[image]

[outer part] = $\displaystyle\frac {r^2(\pi - \theta)}{2} - \frac {r^2(\sin (\pi - \theta))}{2}$

[central part] = $\displaystyle 2 \cdot \frac {r^2(\sin (\pi - \theta))}{2} + \frac {r^2(2 \cdot \theta)}{2}$

Equating the two, we get $\pi = 3 \theta + 3 \sin \theta$

Answer (score 1):

HINT   the area of the smaller segment bounded by AB is $$\frac 12r^2(\alpha-\sin\alpha),$$ where $\alpha=\pi-\theta$, so set this equal to $\frac 13\pi r^2$

Comment: How does $\alpha=\pi-\theta$ come?Rest of the method i understood.Thanks.

Comment: you have angle BAO=angle ABO =$\frac 12\theta$, so angle AOB $=\alpha=\pi-\theta$